# WCF to Named Pipe does not work when run as a Scheduled Task

Tags: wcf, scheduled-tasks, named-pipes

I created a process monitoring program (C#) that uses WCF to handle logging from a number of processes that I am running on a server.  Everything is local to the server, and the WCF base address is "net.pipe://localhost/ServiceDebugHost".   When I run them from Explorer, they open the connection to the monitoring program and send it messages, which it displays.

However, when I run them under the Task Scheduler (Windows Server 2008R2), no messages arrive.  I have the scheduled task run under an admin account.

The server's Service Model is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service name="ServiceDebugHost.CommService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ServiceDebugHost.ICommService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/ServiceDebugHost" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The client Service Mode is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICommService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/ServiceDebugHost" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICommService" contract="LogService.ICommService"
            name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICommService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any thoughts why it won't send the messages under Task Scheduler?

Thanks.

Here is the Exception as presented in Event Viewer:

```
Application: Monitor.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException
Stack:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationPool`2.TakeConnection(EndpointAddress address, Uri via, TimeSpan timeout, TKey& key)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32)
   at Monitor.LogService.ICommService.ServiceMessage(System.String, Int32, System.String)
   at Monitor.Program.Log(Int32, System.String)
   at Monitor.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: I took out the try/catch around my call to the service, and now I get an error in event viewer: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException Stack: Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings) at ...

Comment: What account does the task run under>?

Comment: It runs under an admin account.  And works fine on another server (exported and imported the task, so the only thing different in the task is the user, which is an administrator in both cases).  So I suspect that there is a server privilege not set the same.

Comment: This is not an answer to why it fails with named pipes, however, if I change to net.tcp it works.

Comment: Can you post the full error as an edit in your original post please?

Comment: Sorry I haven't got any solution for you :(